# JBoss 4.0.3 Start up Error jgroups

Tags: jboss, jgroups

I know this is an older version of JBoss, but I'm really scratching my head as to what to look for with the errors provided by the log on startup. It seems that it is unhappy with the configuration for jgroups? Here are the log entires that might help:

```
15:33:38,696 ERROR [STDERR] 102 [DownHandler (UDP)] INFO org.jgroups.protocols.UDP
15:33:38,699 ERROR [STDERR] 105 [DownHandler (UDP)] INFO org.jgroups.protocols.UDP

15:33:41,529 ERROR [STDERR] 2935 [main] INFO org.jboss.cache.TreeCache
15:33:43,333 ERROR [URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:
...
```

I apologize for the lack of any detailed info, but everything in the socket information seems correct. I know this is a long shot, thank you to anyone who can help.

Edit: Link to pastebin for more detailed log: https://pastebin.com/Z5yCjq99

Comment: I know this might not be of much help but have you looked at [this](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/174462) or these [results](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US725&ei=hE1hWsKTBNiojwPVl7fQCQ&q=%22STDERR+DownHandler+%28UDP%29%5D+%22+jgroups&oq=%22STDERR+DownHandler+%28UDP%29%5D+%22+jgroups&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5355.5355.0.5955.1.1.0.0.0.0.92.92.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.-OrZz7ViNBs) i seem to recall in past that TCP works way better (and more reliable(though more overhead)) than UDP - hope its helpful at all, good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the info, JGlass. I have searched for that string in Google and didn't seem to have success with the first few results. I also unfortuantly already have the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` argument in my start up command.

Comment: Still looking around but this might work though its for JBoss EAP 5 `-Djboss.default.jgroups.stack=tcp`

Comment: Bingo!  This answer should get you going - it is TCP but the whole section, while you have to click through pages is all about JGroups on JBoss EAP 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you take a look at [JBoss 4.2 Clustering Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/beta422/html/jbosscache-jgroups-transport-tcp.html) whether you got the UDP route or the TCP route - also, I dont know how involved a network setup you have with switches and routers - but our IP engineering team had to setup UDP multicast IP's and ports when we did JBoss EAP 6 clusters

**From the guide, and with regards to TCP**

Alternatively, a JGroups-based cluster can also work over TCP connections. Compared with UDP, TCP generates more network traffic when the cluster size increases. TCP is fundamentally a unicast protocol. To send multicast messages, JGroups uses multiple TCP unicasts. To use TCP as a transport protocol, you should define a TCP element in the JGroups Config element. Here is an example of the TCP element.

```
<TCP start_port="7800"
bind_addr="192.168.5.1"
loopback="true"
down_thread="false" up_thread="false"/>`
```

Theres a lot more information on the page - and if you click one page back, its the UDP setup

UDP is the preferred protocol for JGroups. UDP uses multicast or multiple unicasts to send and receive messages. If you choose UDP as the transport protocol for your cluster service, you need to configure it in the UDP sub-element in the JGroups Config element. Here is an example.

```
<UDP mcast_addr="${jboss.partition.udpGroup:228.1.2.3}" 
 mcast_port="${jboss.hapartition.mcast_port:45566}"
 tos="8"
 ucast_recv_buf_size="20000000"
 ucast_send_buf_size="640000"
 mcast_recv_buf_size="25000000"
 mcast_send_buf_size="640000"
 loopback="false"
 discard_incompatible_packets="true"
 enable_bundling="false"
 max_bundle_size="64000"
 max_bundle_timeout="30"
 use_incoming_packet_handler="true"
 use_outgoing_packet_handler="false"
 ip_ttl="${jgroups.udp.ip_ttl:2}"
 down_thread="false" up_thread="false"/>`
```

The next 20 pages of clicks or so go into all the different types of setups you can use!

**Update** I also just found the better [pdf](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/4.2/pdf/server_configuration_guide/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform-4.2-Server_Configuration_Guide-en-US.pdf) version of the documentation!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that info. I've got some more detail in the logs, I'm still getting the error though:

Comment: You might update your question with the latest log entries - ditto your 
pertinent configuration section see if we can get things straightened out.  Also any java options you might be passing as well as the jboss params/arg's you're passing on Jboss start.  I also just found a better document!,  Updating answer with it!

Comment: Sorry, was trying to get a pastebin link in the edit:  https://pastebin.com/Z5yCjq99

Comment: This doesnt look correct? `;mcast_addr=230.X.X.X` - it think thats just a generic description, e.g. fill in X.X.X see [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JGRP-1808) i know Mac OS is irrelevant but still good info - also note what I mentioned earlier - see how they mention routes even for the loopback?  Looks like you may not need to do it for windows or Linux for sure.  I'd recommend commenting out that entry and replace it with the default `${jboss.partition.udpGroup:228.1.2.3}` and see if it helps.

Comment: It also looks like you have no members other than the one, not sure if that might cause your problem - doesnt seem like it would, you'd just see errors - oh, also check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432406/jboss-4-2-2-nodes-start-to-cluster-then-suspect-each-other?rq=1) as per that answer try `run.sh -c default -b 10.51.1.131 -Djgroups.bind_addr=10.51.1.131` replacing 10.51.1.131 with your real IP Address

Comment: Yeah, I added the X's to the mcast address to scrub them but its a valid address in the config. I've also set Djgroups.bind_addr to the boxes IP and tried that with the same results, sadly.

Comment: Are you doing this on windows or linux - hopefully linux, and I'd leave the real IP bindings for now.  Are you also using the default UDP group above - it might help to simplify things

Comment: Also try the "all" configuration - someone also mentioned that - well dang, then I guess you'd need to update that configuration with your changes but may be worth a shot - they say the default doesnt have all the workings

Comment: So it seems I have a different error further down now
`[ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss:service=TransactionManager`

Comment: Thats a really strange error - it looks as if theres a jar file mismatch?  You havent touched or replaced any of the default jars that come with JBoss have you - or including any jars in your deployment which might be affecting JBoss's installed jars?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, this system has been running as-is for quite some time.

Comment: A restart doesnt cure it?  If that doesnt work - can you undeploy any custom WAR's, EAR's and JAR's you might have deployed (obviously if its not production ;-) ) restart and see if that helps - else, maybe undo the last change you tried with regards to Jgroups as maybe that is causing the error.  With regards to the original issue, if you want to paste any pertinent config changes you have - cleaned a bit - I could try and reproduce your issue and see if I can get it working locally

Comment: Did you get it figured out fin1te?

Comment: Hey JGlass, we ended up having to recover from a pervious snapshot of the machine. The root cause is still unknown, but all the information you provided did ensure that the clustering configuration was good! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @fin1te you're very welcome!  If you think the answer was decent enough or might help others please feel free to select it as the right answer!  Glad you got things working!